# Const Variable Value Keep Changing React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React Beginner. I wanted to randomize options with every page load. Correct option is the first element of array.Correct MCQ option value keeps changing. Even tho I defined it before `shuffle()` array function. What i'm doing wrong?
React Version: ^17.0.2

```
import React from 'react';
import mcqContent from './mcq-content';
const MCQPage = ({match}) =>{
    const reqUrl = match.params.name;
    const mcqData = mcqContent.find(mcqData => mcqData.m_slug === reqUrl);
    const correctMcq = mcqData.m_alternatives[0];
    const optionsArray = mcqData.m_alternatives
    const shuffledArray = shuffle(optionsArray)
    return (
    <>
        <h1>{mcqData.m_title}</h1><br/>
        <h3>{mcqData.m_question}</h3>
        {shuffledArray.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
            ))}
        <h4>Answer: {correctMcq}</h4>
    </>
    );
};
export default MCQPage; 
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
  
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: Your shuffle function uses the Fisher–Yates algorithm, which shuffles the input array in place. So it mutates `optionsArray`. You can operate on a shallow copy of the original array by calling `shuffle(optionsArray.slice())` instead. This will not modify `optionsArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing an array as a function argument it's passed as a reference, meaning a reference to the original array. I think the safest solution would be to always make a copy of the original array inside the function and return the newly created and modified array (so no matter who is using the function the original array is never changed).

```js
function shuffle(options) {
    const array = [...options];
    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
  
    return array;
  }
```